# Wordpress phpmailer custom plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, phpmailer

I have change over from a html/php website to a wordpress cms website for our local residents association, all is fine except for the email bit.
My only experience of wordpress is the custom build I have had fun with over the past few months, I have no real understanding how wordpress reacts with phpmailer, except that a version is wrapped in wp_mail, which I was trying to avoid, hoping to go direct to my server.
I have an existing phpmailer smtp script that works great on the old site, I have tried various methods to implement this on wordpress, with no success, I figured out that if I make it a plugin then a lot of problems disappear, like formatting on the page etc, in my mind this is important.
Can someone please help me or explain to me why this is not working and what I must do to get this script to work.

````
  /**
   * Author: <a href="tony@test.uk">tony</a>
   * Version: 1.0.0
   * Plugin Name: Email Form Plugin
   * Description: This is a Contact Us Page Email Form Plugin
   **/
  
   function email_form_plugin()
   {
     $content = '';
     $content .= '<h3>Contact Us</h3>';
     $content .= '<form method="post" action="">';
     $content .= '<select class="select" name="recipients" id="recipients">
     <option value="choose_recipient" selected>Choose Recipient</option>
     <option value="chair">Chair :&emsp; John Smith</option>
     <option value="vice_chair">Vice Chair :&emsp; Linda Smith</option>
     <option value="secretary">Secretary :&emsp; Terry Smith</option>
     <option value="treasurer">Treasurer :&emsp; Colin Smith</option>
     <option value="membership_secretary">Membership Secretary :&emsp; Victor Smith</option>
     <option value="highways_officer">Highways Officer :&emsp; Richard Smith</option>
     <option value="environmental_officer">Environmental Officer :&emsp; Martin Smith</option>
     <option value="schools_liaison_officer">Schools Liaison Officer :&emsp; Julie Smith</option>
     <option value="events_co-ordinator">Events Co-ordinator :&emsp; Susan Smith</option>
     <option value="webmaster">Webmaster :&emsp; David Smith</option>
     <option value="suggestion">Suggestion :&emsp; RA Committee</option>
   </select>';
  
     $content .= '<select class="select" name="title">                        
     <option value="" selected>Choose Your Title</option>
     <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
     <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
     <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
     <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
   </select>';
  
     $content .= '<input type="text" name="firstname" class="select" id="firstname" maxlength="20" placeholder="Enter First Name" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" title="Please use letters only, no other characters" autocomplete="off" required>';
  
     $content .= '<input type="text" name="lastname" class="select" id="lastname" maxlength="30" placeholder="Enter Last Name" pattern="[A-Za-z\s]+" title="Please use letters and spaces only, no other characters" autocomplete="off" required>';
  
     $content .= '<input type="email" name="email" class="select" id="email" maxlength="55" placeholder="Enter Email Address" pattern="^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" title="Please make sure your email address is correct" autocomplete="off" required>';
  
     $content .= '<input type="tel" name="mobile" class="select" placeholder="Enter Mobile/Phone Number" pattern="^[0-9\s]*$" title="Please use numbers and spaces only" autocomplete="off">';
  
     $content .= '<input type="text" name="topic" class="select" id="topic" maxlength="60" placeholder="Enter Your Topic" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+" title="Please use letters, numbers and spaces only, no other characters" autocomplete="off" required>';
  
     $content .= '<textarea cols="60" rows="8" name="info" class="select" id="info" placeholder="Write Your Question or Suggestion Here!" title="Please write your question or suggestion here!" autocomplete="off" required></textarea>';
      
     $content .= '<div id="entry1" class="attachment-row"> 
     <input name="attachment[]" class="select" type="file" id="attachment" multiple="multiple"> 
   </div>';
  
     $content .= '<div onClick="addMoreAttachment();" id="btnAdd" name="btnAdd" class="icon-add-more-attachemnt" title="Add More Attachments">
     <p>Add More Attachments &ensp;
     <img width="16" height="16" src="https://test.uk/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/icon-add-more-attachment.png" alt="Add More Attachments"></p>        
   </div>';
  
     $content .= '<div><br> <button type="submit" class="btn btn--dark-purple" name="email_form_submit">Send Email</button> </div>';
  
     $content .='</form>';
  
     return $content;
  
   }
   add_shortcode('email_form', 'email_form_plugin');
   
  // all above works fine and renders well on the contact page.
  //-----------------------------------------------------------
  //session_start();
  
  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
  
  require_once(\ABSPATH . \WPINC . "/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php");
  require_once(\ABSPATH . \WPINC . "/PHPMailer/Exception.php");       
  require_once(\ABSPATH . \WPINC . "/PHPMailer/SMTP.php");
  
  $results = '';
  
  if (array_key_exists('attachment', $_FILES)) {
  
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
  
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
    $topic = $_POST['topic'];    
    $info = $_POST['info'];   
  
      $addresses = [
          'choose_recipient' =>         'Mark@test.uk',  // used as a default recipient if no recipient chosen.
          'chair' =>                    'John@test.uk',
          'vice_chair' =>               'Linda@test.uk',
          'secretary' =>                'Terry@test.uk',
          'treasurer' =>                'Colin@test.uk',
          'membership_secretary' =>     'Victor@test.uk',
          'highways_officer' =>         'Richard@test.uk',
          'environmental_officer' =>    'Martin@test.uk',
          'schools_liaison_officer' =>  'Julie@test.uk',
          'events_co-ordinator' =>      'Susan@test.uk',
          'webmaster' =>                'David@test.uk',
          'suggestion' =>               'Mike@test.uk',
      ];
          
      if (array_key_exists('recipients', $_POST) && array_key_exists($_POST['recipients'], $addresses)) {
    $mail->addAddress($addresses[$_POST['recipients']]);
      } else {
    //Fall back to fixed address if selection invalid
    $mail->addAddress('Mark@test.uk');
      }       
  
      
      $mail->isSMTP();
      $mail->HOST        = 'mail.test.uk';
      $mail->SMTPAuth    = true;
      $mail->Port        = 465;
      $mail->Username    = 'ra@test.uk';
      $mail->Password    = '************';
      $mail->SMTPSecure  = 'ssl';
      $mail->From        = 'ra@test.uk';
      $mail->FromName    = 'RA';
      $mail->SMTPDebug   = 2; 
      
      $mail->setFrom($email, $firstname, $lastname);
      $mail->isHTML(true);                                  
      $mail->Subject = $topic;
  
          $body = 
              "<h2> Residents' Association </h2>
              <h3>You have received a message from our contact form:</h3>
              From: $title $firstname $lastname <br><br>      
              Email Contact: $email <br><br>
              Phone Contact: $mobile <br><br>
              Regarding: $topic <br><br>
              Message: $info <br><br>";  
      $mail->Body    = $body;
      $mail->AltBody = strip_tags($body);
  
      for ($ct = 0, $ctMax = count($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name']); $ct < $ctMax; $ct++) {
          $ext = PHPMailer::mb_pathinfo($_FILES['attachment']['name'][$ct], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);              
          $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $_FILES['attachment']['name'][$ct])) . '.' . $ext;
          $filename = $_FILES['attachment']['name'][$ct];
          if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'][$ct], $uploadfile)) {
              if (!$mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename)) {
                  $results = "Failed to attach file " . $filename;
              }
          } else {
             // $results = "Failed to move file to " . $uploadfile;  //  if I send email without attachment - I get error message
          }
      }
  
  
      if (!$mail->send()) {
          $results = "Something went wrong......";
      } else {
        $result="Your inquiry has been submitted, a member of our team will get in touch with you within 24 hours.";
  }
  }  
  
  ?> ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not including your own copy of PHPMailer as it's less likely to be updated when things are updated in WordPress.

You can get hold of WordPress' PHPMailer instance by writing a function that you can then link to WordPress' `phpmailer_init` hook:

```php
add_action('phpmailer_init', 'mailer_config');
function mailer_config(PHPMailer $mailer){
  $mailer->isSMTP();
  $mailer->Host = "mail.example.com"; // your SMTP server
  $mailer->Port = 25;
  $mailer->SMTPDebug = 2;
  $mailer->CharSet  = "utf-8";
  //etc
}
```

Having set that up, this config will then be used when you call `wp_mail()`.

Separately, to create your template, you'll find it much easier to work with PHP's [heredoc syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) than all those concat operations.

Comment: Hi Synchro,
Thank you for your quick response, I forgot to mention that this theme is a custom made theme built by me from scratch, nothing like diving into the deep end. I have now solved this issue and it is working fine, thank you, as regarding the Heredoc link which is eye opening. I will be making use of this.

Comment: There are plugins that provide an admin user interface for setting up PHPMailer in WordPress through that route, and once it’s set you just call wp_mail from your other code.

Comment: I've [added this info to PHPMailer docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-PHPMailer-in-WordPress).